# React Hooks: Hide/Show elements from other components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a project that has global navigation. Inside the nav is a button that should be able to hide certain elements with class "en".

inside the `nav.js` file

this is the code for the button

```
<Button id="switch-lang" onClick={translate}>ENGLISH</Button>
```

and this is currently the function I have

```
function translate(){
        const handleSwitchLang = (dataLang) => {
            if (lang === switchedLang){
                setSwitchLang('');
            } else {
                setSwitchLang(dataLang);
            }
        };
    }
```

in the `context.js`

```
export const SwitchLangContext = createContext();
```

and in my `homecontent.js`

```
    const [switchedLang, setSwitchLang = useState(true);

    const context = useContext(SwitchLangContext);
```

This should be my div that I want to hide

```
<div className="en">
 This is my planned content
</div>
```

I'm quite unsure how do I hide elements with class 'en' in React Hooks. I've done something similar but it's on the same file. Now these are on two different files, I'm quite unsure how.

Answer (score 0):

**One way of hiding elements based on props is to do this:**

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
    const contentNode = null;
    if (props.switchedLang === true) {
        contentNode = (
            <div className="en">
                This is my planned content
            </div>
        );
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {contentNode}  
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

**Alternatively, one could apply a CSS class to the parent that hides them.**

```
.lang-switched .en {
    visibility: hidden;
    // or
    display: none;
}
```

then

```
<div className={`content${props.switchedLang && ' lang-switched')`}>
    <div className="en">
        This is my planned content
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```